# Will Blazor WebAssembly use Mono or .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

Since Microsoft says that Blazor WebAssembly is in preview for .Net Core 3.1 (see [that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)), does it mean that Mono is replaced by .Net Core 3.1 in Blazor Web Assembly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blazor WebAssembly will still use Mono. All the WASM implementations have. It’s the preferred client .net runtime

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is Mono the prefered runtime ? .Net Core is more modular and lightweight than Mono. Is it because .Net Core does not run on Android yet ?

Comment: This will change the end of next year with .Net core 5 which merges all the .nets into one [DotNet Road Map](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/)

Comment: @CyrilSeguenot they chose Mono because it's the preferred client runtime for .NET and was already being developed for WASM. You can see Steve's comments at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2017/11/05/blazor-on-mono/

Comment: @CyrilSeguenot Mono is preferred for it's more lightweight rather than downloading the whole CLR runtime each time you load a Blazor WASM for the 1st time.